# Issue with Geolocation HTML5

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple code which is for Geolocation through asking the user for permission & allow to get his location when he press a simple button, when I run the file on my desktop it works and the button function, but if I upload it to a hosting like a free host [http://darkdays.byethost14.com/cc.html] the button will not work means no thing pop-up!

Thanks for help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get Current Position</title>
<script>
    function showPosition() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var positionInfo = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo;
            });
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Position information will be inserted here-->
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPosition();">Show Position</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything here runs in the browser, so as long as the server is serving the page it must be related to the browser settings. Maybe your browser is set to not allow location requests if the page is served from a remote site.

Comment: I have tried it on different computers , also on phone devices same issue! 
@RiggsFoll

Comment: Maybe you should [lookup Secure Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation) Maybe that is your issue. Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and  http://*.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely.

Comment: I am not sure how likely it is you will be able to get a ssl certificate for a free hosting site

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? Is there anything logged to the browser's console? Also, how is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The website needs to have an ssl certificate. Only then can you use any of the `navigator` properties. It also works as a local file.
Most (probably all) free hosting services don't provide ssl certificates for free, so you're using the `http` protocol and not `https`.